# Display Jasper report file name

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm creating a jasper report using iReports 5.2.0 and I want to display the report file name in it.

Can't find any variable that has that information and I would like to get an alternative to pass it in the parameters.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you design your report, make a new PARAMETER named, for instance: NAME_REPORT.
After that, put a TextField in your report, for example, in your Title section, and
put as value of your TextField the parameter like a expression: $P{NAME_REPORT}

When you preview your report, ask you to give a value to this parameter and then, you see the title with the name
of your report file.

In your java code you will do somethink like that:

```
parameters.put("NAME_REPORT", "myreport.jrxml");
.....
JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, connection)
.....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I understood correctly that way I would have to pass the name in the parameters and what I would like is an alternative to that.

Comment: You can use a StaticText and write there the file name if it is always the same.  
Other way, It's use Scriptlets, and make a method where you pass the parameter and return the name,of this way
you can use a expression such as $P{SCRIPLET_REPORNAME}.getNameReport(<your_param_in>) in your TextField